# Upload files using Web API and Windows application in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, multipartform-data, filestream

I need to upload files from client machine to a remote server and for that i have created a windows application which will work as client. It will select the required file and call the Web API.

Please find my client code as below :

```
 //...other code removed for brevity

        private void UploadFile(string filename)
    {
        Stream ms = new MemoryStream();
        using (FileStream file = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            var fileInfo = new FileInfo(filename);
            byte[] bytes = new byte[file.Length];
            file.Read(bytes, 0, (int)file.Length);
            ms.Write(bytes, 0, (int)file.Length);

            MultiPartFormUpload multiPartFormUpload = new MultiPartFormUpload();
            List<FileInfo> files = new List<FileInfo>() { fileInfo };

            try
            {
                MultiPartFormUpload.UploadResponse response = multiPartFormUpload.Upload("http://localhost:10458/api/Upload", files);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }

 public class MultiPartFormUpload
{
    public class MimePart
    {
        NameValueCollection _headers = new NameValueCollection();
        byte[] _header;

        public NameValueCollection Headers
        {
            get { return _headers; }
        }

        public byte[] Header
        {
            get { return _header; }
        }

        public long GenerateHeaderFooterData(string boundary)
        {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            stringBuilder.Append("--");
            stringBuilder.Append(boundary);
            stringBuilder.AppendLine();
            foreach (string key in _headers.AllKeys)
            {
                stringBuilder.Append(key);
                stringBuilder.Append(": ");
                stringBuilder.AppendLine(_headers[key]);
            }
            stringBuilder.AppendLine();

            _header = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringBuilder.ToString());

            return _header.Length + Data.Length + 2;
        }

        public Stream Data { get; set; }
    }

    public class UploadResponse
    {
        public UploadResponse(HttpStatusCode httpStatusCode, string responseBody)
        {
            HttpStatusCode = httpStatusCode;
            ResponseBody = responseBody;
        }

        public HttpStatusCode HttpStatusCode { get; set; }

        public string ResponseBody { get; set; }
    }

    public UploadResponse Upload(string url, List<FileInfo> files)
    {
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            List<MimePart> mimeParts = new List<MimePart>();

            try
            {


                foreach (FileInfo file in files)
                {
                    MimePart part = new MimePart();
                    string name = file.Extension.Substring(1);
                    string fileName = file.Name;

                    part.Headers["Content-Disposition"] = "form-data; name=\"" + name + "\"; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"";
                    part.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/octet-stream";

                    part.Data = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(file.FullName));

                    mimeParts.Add(part);
                }

                string boundary = "----------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");
                client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);

                long contentLength = 0;

                byte[] _footer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("--" + boundary + "--\r\n");

                foreach (MimePart mimePart in mimeParts)
                {
                    contentLength += mimePart.GenerateHeaderFooterData(boundary);
                }

                byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
                byte[] afterFile = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("\r\n");
                int read;

                using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    foreach (MimePart mimePart in mimeParts)
                    {
                        memoryStream.Write(mimePart.Header, 0, mimePart.Header.Length);

                        while ((read = mimePart.Data.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                            memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);

                        mimePart.Data.Dispose();

                        memoryStream.Write(afterFile, 0, afterFile.Length);
                    }

                    memoryStream.Write(_footer, 0, _footer.Length);
                    byte[] responseBytes = client.UploadData(url, memoryStream.ToArray());
                    string responseString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBytes);
                    return new UploadResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, responseString);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                foreach (MimePart part in mimeParts)
                    if (part.Data != null)
                        part.Data.Dispose();

                if (ex.GetType().Name == "WebException")
                {
                    WebException webException = (WebException)ex;
                    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webException.Response;
                    string responseString;

                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
                    {
                        responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }

                    return new UploadResponse(response.StatusCode, responseString);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please find Web API code as below :

```
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post()
    {
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
        }

        string fileSaveLocation = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/upload/files");
        CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider provider = new CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider(fileSaveLocation);
        List<string> files = new List<string>();

        try
        {
            await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

            foreach (MultipartFileData file in provider.FileData)
            {
                files.Add(Path.GetFileName(file.LocalFileName));
            }

            // Send OK Response along with saved file names to the client.
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, files);
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e);
        }
    }

    public class CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider : MultipartFormDataStreamProvider
    {
    public CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider(string path) : base(path) { }

    public override string GetLocalFileName(HttpContentHeaders headers)
    {
        return headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Replace("\"", string.Empty);
    }
}
```

I am able to hit the Web API with the client code but **fileInfo.Length** is coming 0.

Please let me know what i am missing in Client or Web API code. Thanks !

Comment: Create object of FileInfo for specified path            
    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(@"D:\DummyFile.txt");

Comment: @NitinLawande : That i  have already created in foreach loop. Could you explain a bit more.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Updated post with working code.